# Is it possible to define your own conversion for a type during serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontract

I'm using the `[DataContract]` attribute on a type to make it serializable. Some of the properties/fields are of a struct type that I do not want to serialize as is, but want to use a custom type strictly for the serialization.

How do I substitute a type for serialization?

Comment: How about [Data Contract Surrogates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Awesome this is what I need, make it the answer and I'll mark it

Comment: I wouldn't like to put up a link-only answer, but glad to help.

Comment: Well if you want to take the time to give a brief overview, that works too :) searching a ton on the web and here I couldn't find what I needed, though I figured there was a way to do it. Of course, I didn't realize the keyword was surrogate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using the `[DataContract]` attribute in .NET, you generally end up serializing the type using a [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). The `DataContractSerializer` has a read-only property named `DataContractSurrogate`. This property is a [IDataContractSurrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. (the read-only property can be set on the constructor or through the [DataContractSerializerSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) type)

That interface contains the logic for transforming one type to another during serialization. There are 8 methods provided by the interface, but for transforming one type to another during serialization and deserialization, you really only need to implement 3. Here is the basic structure of a class that implements the interface where you can substitute your types and transform logic.

```
internal class SerializerSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies a type transformation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type being inspected.</param>
    /// <returns>The type to transform to. If the same type is used, transform does not happen.</returns>
    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(sourceType))
            return typeof(targetType);

        return type;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// During serialization, transfrom from sourceType to targetType.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object instance.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The source type.</param>
    /// <returns>A new object instance based on targetType.</returns>
    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is sourceType)
        {
            // Create instance of targetType from the obj variable which is sourceType
            // Set the properties of the targetType, based on the (sourceType)obj variable.
            return new targetType();
        }

        return obj;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// During deserialization, transform from targetType to sourceType.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object instance.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The target type.</param>
    /// <returns>A new object instance based on sourceType.</returns>
    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is targetType)
        {
            // Create instance of sourceType from the obj variable which is targetType
            // Set the properties of the sourceType, based on the (targetType)obj variable.
            return new sourceType();
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```